Trying to retrieve Windows user data with ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am trying to check the current user's Windows credentials to see if the user can be matched to a user in my application's database and if so I will log them in with bearer token.
I only need to see the name of the currently logged in user and that is it, no complex authentication or authorization so obviously anonymous auth needs to stay.
User is currently always empty running both from Visual Studio or on IIS.
My files:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Controller:
[HttpGet(EP_GET_WIN_USER)]
public ActionResult GetWinUser()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;

    if (user != null)
    {
        return Ok(user);
    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}

LaunchSettings:
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,

I have checked all available forums and videos without success. In case further information is needed please let me know.

You could try following:
Install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate
In the program.cs using NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme :
// remove "builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)"
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

On top of the Controller action, you could add Authorize attribute with specific scheme
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet(EP_GET_WIN_USER)]
    public ActionResult GetWinUser()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;

        ...
    }

Then "windowsAuthentication": true, will work for visual studio. IIS also works if you enable Windows Autentication.

